# How can I show that there is no current over resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, wheatstone-bridge, y-to-delta

I made a contest question regarding find the entire current provide from voltage source 45V connected between a-c terminals. Follow the picture below:

Original circuit

[image]

My resolution
[image]

I can made it but i have some issues about the decimal number and hard work to the numerical solution (sucks). In fact, my curiosity appears and i decide to simulate on Everycircuit and bingo. I realize that the resistor between point d and b doesn't consume any current.

[image]

But i cant figure out why this situation happen. Any suggestion to visualize this? tips?

Thank u!

Comment: Remove d, b resistor and you should will see that now you have two voltage dividers. And the voltage on the d side is 45/2 And the same voltage is on the side b. Thus, no current will flow if you connect a resistor between points d and b. Do you see it?

Comment: Why no current? The voltage over resistor must be 0V for that to happen, right? Yes can be seen better if the circuit is redrawn to be more clear, it is now drawn like trick questions usually are, it looks confusing.

Comment: Tip: in English we don't say current "over" a resistor, we say "current through a resistor" and, usually, "voltage across a resistor".

Comment: yes man, ty. I see it!.  @Justme yes man. I tried to redrawn the circuit using convert delta-y in the first place but i didnt like the numbers of new resistors. the new schematic below right after my question is pretty clear!

Comment: @Transistor ty for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOf5Ow.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 9 ohm (A-D, D-C) and 6 ohm (A-B, B-C) resistors each form a voltage divider with 22.5V at their midpoints.  Since the 9 ohm resistor between B-D has the same voltage at both ends, no current flows through it.